# Lego technic 42082 4 wheel steering issue

Tags: technic, building, instructions

I have just completed the build and everything appears to work as it should except the 4 wheel steering. When you turn the small wheel on the rear of the crane only the rear wheels steer. The front wheels will steer if you move them manually, but not in tandem with the rear wheels. Has anyone else encountered this? Am hoping it is an easy fix

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed step 273 on page 133 of book 1.

In this step you align the front and back wheel and move a gear wheel and bush so the front steering mechanism is connected to the rest.

To fix this you need to disassemble part of the front

- After taken of the fenders
- Follow steps 471 till 484 in reverse.

This removes the panel above the gear so you should be able to access the gear.

Comment: Same thing happened to me when I build the thing last year. I was so focused on aligning the front and back wheels I overlooked that the gear and bush needed to be moved in. Luckily I'm in the habit of trying every moving part after assembly to see if it moves freely and isn't overly tight. So I noticed straight away that the front wheels weren't steering. And when they give you alignment instructions it is clear they should have moved together or else those alignment instructions wouldn't make sense at this point in the build.